# C# Serilog error when *.deps.json is deleted

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, serilog, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using VS2019 and i have added the following in the post build event. When i start the application i get error saying `<projectname>.deps.json` not found

```
RD /S /Q "$(OutDir)e2e-cypress"
del $(OutDir)*.deps.json
del $(OutDir)*.pdb
```

Please help me with the right solution.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you delete this ```deps.json``` file?

Comment: as that file is not required in production environment. so to reduce file size and audit purpose it has to be deleted. so was deleting it.